# authenticated encryption in Java 7

Tags: java, encryption-symmetric

I want to use authenticated encryption in my code. According to the JDK, it seems that **java 7 support AES/GCM/NoPadding**.

However, I got the following error with the following code.

**Error:**

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/GCM/NoPadding
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:524)
    at CipherService.main(CipherService.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

**Code:**

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
final int blockSize = c.getBlockSize();
final byte[] ivData = new byte[blockSize];
final SecureRandom rnd = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
rnd.nextBytes(ivData);
GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(blockSize * Byte.SIZE, ivData);
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
byte[] aesKey = new byte[KEY_SIZE];
byte[] ciphertext;
byte[] head = "Head".getBytes();
byte[] data = "Data".getBytes();
sr.nextBytes(aesKey);
SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey, "AES");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks, params);
c.updateAAD(head);
ciphertext = c.doFinal(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

In short, you cannot (as Brett Pyke said). Because SunJCE crypto provider (and Oracle) does not include AES/GCM implementation. Thankfully, they included at least the GCMParameterSpec.

Your only two options (AFAIK) are crypto providers [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) and [IAIK](http://jce.iaik.tugraz.at).

**Edit/update**: Oracle JDK-8 seems to provide a working implementation of AES/GCM.

Comment: One caveat however: Oracle JDK-8 implementation of AES/GCM is a whole order of magnitude slower than BouncyCastle pure Java AES/GCM implementation (tested on Mac OS X Intel Core i5 and i7). However with AES/CBC, Oracle code is about three times faster than BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an encryption provider such as [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). Once you register it in your context, then you should be able to use any supported algorithm. Your other choice is to use the built in Sun/Oracle provided ones, but this violates the point of Java, being able to run the app on any JVM.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use the built in Sun/Oracle provided ones? Any idea?